# Multi Threading with Spring Boot

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and Java 8

For calling an api with 1 employee id it takes 1 miliseconds .So if I am calling API 100,000 times with 100,000 times with different employee id
why it is taking hours and not 100,000*1 millis i.e just 1.6 minutes

Answer (score 5):

SpringBoot uses a thread pool to manage the workload for working on tasks. Thus, the max worker threads, is set as 200 by default.

Though this is a good number, the number of threads that can work in parallel depends upon the CPU time slicing and availability of backend resources. Assuming, that the backend resources are unlimited, the throughput will solely depend upon the CPU time available for each thread. In a multi-core CPU, it would be the maximum cores available and are able to serve the embedded tomcat container.

As Spring is a blocking framework, for a normal quad-core single CPU environment (assuming that all 4 cores are able to serve), this no. is 4. This means a maximum of 4 requests can be served in parallel. Rest all are likely to be queued and taken up when the next CPU slice is available.

#### Mathematical analysis:

Time taken by the API to process 1 request = 1ms 
Time is taken by the API to process 4 concurrent requests = 1ms  
Time taken by the API to process 1000,000 concurrent requests = 1000000 / 4 = 250 secs

This is just the best-case scenario. In real scenarios, all the CPUs are less likely to provide a time slice at the same instant. So, you are likely to see differences.

In such scenarios, it would be better to use the Spring Reactive than the conventional Spring framework in SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0):

The API you're pulling from could be limit the amount of requests you can pull in a certain period of time. If you don't have access to the API source, I would attempt to run larger and larger numbers of pulls until you notice it takes significantly longer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the time needed to get response from a web server depends on it's hosting machine and environment.

Usually in a single machine a limited number of thread inside a thread pool and each request is bound with one thread. So while making concurrent request every time certain number of request is processed within the available threads and rest awaits in the queue.

This can be the reason that your requests are taking a while to get response or even some of them can get a request time out.